# Spring data Querydsl in eclipse not generating query type classes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I don't see query dsl classes generated in eclipse
added below dependency and plugin in the pom.xml.
Can some please review below change required for query-dsl integration in spring boot?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--Plugin for query-dsl -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
             <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

`

Comment: In eclipse, sometimes you have to refresh your project multiple times to see the generated-sources. If not try to generate the files by right click on your project -> run as -> maven generate sources.

Comment: Thanks source are generated in the target folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In eclipse, sometimes you have to refresh your project multiple times to see the generated-sources. If not try to generate the files by

```
right click on your project -> run as -> maven generate sources.
```

Comment: Ohh nice help!! with a maven command-line will be: `mvn clean compile`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to annotation processing of M2E. New Eclipse versions contain an experimental feature, which delegates annotation processing to maven plugins and thus behaves the same as using mvn from the command line.

To enable the feature:

1. rightclick a project and select properties
2. in the properties navigate to `Maven -> Annotation Processing`
3. to enable this option for the whole workspace and not just for this specific module select `Configure Workspace Settings`[image]
4. Select `Experimental: Delegate annotation processing to maven plugins (for maven processor only)`.[image]
5. Click Apply.

This way Eclipse processes annotations with the plugins defined in the `pom.xml`. Resources are now generated when building the project and also found as dependency. No need to build the project manually with maven.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies you added are correct.It generates Q types for classes annotated with @Entity.This annotation is from package jakarta.persistence in later versions. It does not recognizes this as entities. Only @Entity from package javax.persistence is recognized by querydsl(5.0.0). Use older versions of spring data jpa. But that is not an ideal solution. Better way to solve this is by altering processor of your plugin and add @QueryEntity annotation in your entities. here's the code.

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

I followed below 2 steps after that Query dsl class stopped giving compilation error.

Enable annotation processing in eclipse.
Add generated package in source in the classpath.