# q classes are not generated in querydsl

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I am developping a java/jee application using spring boot as framework and i want to filter entity application,so i tried to use querydsl and now i am trying to generate Q classes of querydsl.But when i make mvn install Q classes are not generated.i am using eclipse neon as ide and and java home is configured to JDK 8.
I am using jpa 2 and hibernate 5.
This is my code:

```
package biz.picosoft.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OrderColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;



@Entity
@Table(name = "application",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "reference")})
public class Application implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "reference") 
    private String  reference;
    @Column(name = "creationDate")
    private Date creationDate;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "deadLine")
    private Date deadLine;
    @Column(name = "appType")
    private String appType;
    @Column(name = "projectId")
    private  Long projectId;
    @OrderColumn(name = "listePiecesJointes")
    private String[] listePiecesJointes;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Date getDeadLine() {
        return deadLine;
    }

    public void setDeadLine(Date deadLine) {
        this.deadLine = deadLine;
    }


    public String getAppType() {
        return appType;
    }

    public void setAppType(String appType) {
        this.appType = appType;
    }

    public Application() {
        super();
    }



    public String getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference(String reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public Long getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(Long projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }
    public String[] getListePiecesJointes() {
        return listePiecesJointes;
    }

    public void setListePiecesJointes(String[] listePiecesJointes) {
        this.listePiecesJointes = listePiecesJointes;
    }
    public Application(String reference, Date creationDate, String status, Date deadLine, String appType,String[] listePiecesJointes,Long projectId) {
        super();
        this.reference = reference;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.status = status;
        this.deadLine = deadLine;
        this.appType = appType;
        this.projectId=projectId;
        this.listePiecesJointes=listePiecesJointes;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((appType == null) ? 0 : appType.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((creationDate == null) ? 0 : creationDate.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((deadLine == null) ? 0 : deadLine.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((projectId == null) ? 0 : projectId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((reference == null) ? 0 : reference.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((status == null) ? 0 : status.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Application other = (Application) obj;
        if (appType == null) {
            if (other.appType != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!appType.equals(other.appType))
            return false;
        if (creationDate == null) {
            if (other.creationDate != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!creationDate.equals(other.creationDate))
            return false;
        if (deadLine == null) {
            if (other.deadLine != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!deadLine.equals(other.deadLine))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (projectId == null) {
            if (other.projectId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!projectId.equals(other.projectId))
            return false;
        if (reference == null) {
            if (other.reference != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!reference.equals(other.reference))
            return false;
        if (status == null) {
            if (other.status != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!status.equals(other.status))
            return false;
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Application [id=" + id + ", reference=" + reference + ", creationDate=" + creationDate + ", status="
                + status + ", deadLine=" + deadLine + ", appType=" + appType + ", projectId=" + projectId + "]";
    }




}
```

this is my maven file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>biz.picosoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>gestionprojetback</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>gestionprojetback</name>
    <description>gestion de projet</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>biz.picosoft.ApplictationBoot</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mysqlconnector-version>5.1.6</org.mysqlconnector-version>
        <querydsl.version>4.1.4</querydsl.version>
        <apt-maven-plugin.version>1.1.3</apt-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mysqlconnector-version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysema.querydsl/querydsl-apt -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysema.querydsl/querydsl-apt -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-apt -->

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems right.

Try this from [Querydsl's documentation](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/reference/html_single/#d0e132)

> If you use Eclipse, run mvn eclipse:eclipse to update your Eclipse project to include target/generated-sources/java as a source folder.
>
> Now you are able to construct JPA query instances and instances of the query domain model.

You may also try [Patrick's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49997285/9381897).